# Trying to run CodeBuild in order to create approval rule in CodeCommit but its returning error [ mapping values are not allowed in this context]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to configure aws cli commands in CodeBuild.

But he Build Spec return this error [YAML_FILE_ERROR: mapping values are not allowed in this context].

This is the buildSpec:

```
   version: 0.2
   phases:
     build:
       commands:
         - aws codecommit create-approval-rule-template \ --approval-rule-template-name 2-approver-rule-for-master \ --approval-rule-template-description "Requires two developers from the team to approve the pull request if the destination branch is master" \ --approval-rule-template-content "{\"Version\": \"2018-11-08\",\"DestinationReferences\": [\"refs/heads/master\"],\"Statements\": [{\"Type\": \"Approvers\",\"NumberOfApprovalsNeeded\": 2}]}"`
```

Comment: This is some partial `buildSpec`, not full. What is the full, correctly formatted version?